# cell.imageView curved corner on first and last cell

Tags: iphone, itunes-app

In the iTunes app on the iphone there is a list of songs or something.

They are in a grouped tableview and the first image has a curved corner to match the top left corner of the grouped tableView.

How would I go about replicating this (and the one at the bottom?)

[image]

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use CoreAnimation with it, you could do something like this:

```
[yourView layer].cornerRadius = 10;
[yourView layer].maskToBounds = YES;
```

where yourView is contentView having all cells inside it. ( This way you get curved corners only on first and last rows )

Cheers,
Krzysztof Zabłocki

Comment: Dont forget to add the QuartzCore Framework and add the #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: The cells superview is the tableview itself, I don't see how could this work, help?